# Block until a form closes? Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that launches formB. I would like forma to be hidden until formb is closed. There may be a change formb is opened by formC and others so i simply cant just create a new form. Is there a way to launch formB, hide and block until close?

Comment: The technique you are describing is displaying a dialog modally. More information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 9):

This should do it.

```
this.Visible = false;
using (formB as new FormB())
    formB.ShowDialog(this);
this.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the main window will get hidden behind the window of another app.

Comment: Hmmm, try calling ShowDialog() without a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnActivate` event to hide the owner and the `Dispose` event to show the owner. This solution works even if form_b isn't called from another form:

Code in form_x:

```
FormB f = new FormB();
f.Show(this);
```

Code in form_b

```
this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.HideOwner);
private void HideOwner(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Owner != null) this.Owner.Hide();
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.Owner != null) this.Owner.Show();
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```