# Wait to get info from a popup form

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, wait

At initialization of a form (the main form), it calls another form to get a bunch of starting input, and then transfers a lot of information:

```
Form3 getup = new Form3();
getup.Show();
example = getup.example;
```

However, I need to wait for this new form information to be complete.

```
Form3 getup = new Form3();
getup.Show();
waitfordone();
example = getup.example;
```

ATM, I've tried using while statements:

```
Form3 getup = new Form3();
getup.Show();
While(getup.visible=true)Console.WriteLine("waiting");
example = getup.example;
```

But this causes a hang... that is to say, it runs, then freezes. I suspect this is because the while loop is eating all the processing. So, I tried making a new thread

```
Form3 getup = new Form3();
Thread t = new Thread(getup.Show());
t.start();
While(getup.visible=false)Console.WriteLine("waiting"); // takes a little bit to open
While(getup.visible=true)Console.WriteLine("waiting"); //waits for close
example = getup.example;
```

But this also causes it to hang. Perhaps for the same reason. I have looked into autoresetevents.

And I tried:

```
AutoResetEvent invisible = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Form3 getup = new Form3();
void setup_invisible(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (getup.Visible == false) invisible.Set();
}
public ... {
getup.VisibilityChanged += new EventHandle(setup_Invisible);
getup.show();
invisible.WaitOne();
... }
// and many other variations on this
```

but alas, it opens form3, closes it (because the thread is done?), and then hangs at `invisible.WaitOne();`

Can someone please explain how to do this, reading is only making me more confused.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222834/block-until-a-form-closes-winforms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you may need is a dialog.

```
Form3 getup = new Form3();
getup.ShowDialog();
example = getup.example;
```

This will pause the execution and only continue once the form is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use events:

```
Form3 getup = new Form3();
getup.Show();
getup.FormClosing += (sender, args) =>
{
  example = getup.example;
}
```

It's important for the current method to finish immediately, so that the UI thread can go on with it's loops.  By attaching to an event handler you ensure that your code is run when it needs to be.  The entire concept of "waiting for the child form to close" is inherently contrary to the design of winforms.

You could also make the form a Dialog popup.

```
Form3 getup = new Form3();
getup.ShowDialog();
example = getup.example;
```

That will work just fine, no unintended freezing.

Comment: @Matt Razza I reverted your edit.  I consider the first method perferred, as it's clearly the intent of the OP to have the dialog not be modal, which isn't in the least a bad thing.

Comment: Why doesn't the OP want the dialog to not be modal?

Comment: @MattRazza It's certainly possible that he wants a modal popup, which is why I included it in my answer, but he is currently not using a modal popup.  This would imply that he wants the parent form to be active while the child form is up.  Since this is a reasonably common use-case, I won't just assume that he meant for it to be modal.  To assume that all popups will always be modal is a mistake in my mind.